# Java getRuntime.exec() - "Fatal error: no such file or directory" in error stream (no exception)

Tags: java, r, runtime.exec

When I try to execute an R-Script in Java (rJava) with getRuntime().exec as it can be seen in the code below, then the error stream of process throws the error message "fatal error: Cannot open file PID_controller3.R: No such file or directory.". There is no exception thrown - when I try to execute the script with Rscript in the same directory via shell, then everything works fine. Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong here?

When I for example change the path of the script in my java code to a non-existing path, the an IOException is thrown. This is not happening when using the correct path but I get this error message which is contained in the error stream of the process.

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.3.0\\bin\\Rscript " + "PID_controller3.R");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println("Read error stream: \"" + line + "\"");

        int code = p.waitFor();

        switch (code) {
        case 0:
            //normal termination, everything is fine
            Log.printLine(code);
            break;
        default:
            Log.printLine(code);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ie){ System.out.println(ie.toString());}
```

Comment: Did you try to provide the absolute path to the .R file ?

Comment: Or the correct relative path, relative to the user's directory.

Comment: First things first: you should not be using `Runtime` to execute commands. Use a `ProcessBuilder` instead.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 1):

When viewed from the OS, a process is forked from another process and inherits all attributes of that process unless told otherwise. Understand that all processes in the system are part of a tree. The only exception to this rule is the root process, which is also the root of the tree, which has a special meaning even to the OS.

Among inherited attributes are the working directory. For instance, in a shell, you can type:

```
$ ls someFile
```

The shell, whose prompt is visible here (`$`) has a given working directory; the command (`ls someFile`) will assume that there is a file named `someFile` in the shell's working directory (since the process which is launched to execute the `ls` command inherits it).

In your case, it turns out that the file you wish to process is not in the current working directory of the process you create. And Java's `Runtime` does not allow you to change this.

But a `ProcessBuilder` does:

```
final Path workingDir = Paths.get("path/to/working/dir");

final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("path/to/command", "thefile")
    .directory(workingDir.toFile());

// obtain a Process using pb.exec()
```